# Extract rows from Matrix according to range indexing?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, vectorization

I have a matrix `A` of `NxM` size. I also have an array `B` containing pairs of indexes which represent the rows of `A` I want to extract.

### Example

```
A = [ 1  2  3 %1
      4  5  6 %2
      7  8  9 %3
     10 11 12 %4
     13 14 15 %5
     16 17 18]%6
B = [1 2
     4 6]
```

I'd want `C` to contain the lines of `A` from 1 to 2 and from 4 to 6

```
C = [ 1  2  3 %1
      4  5  6 %2
     10 11 12 %4
     13 14 15 %5
     16 17 18]%6
```

Is there a way to this without iterating over `B`?
I tried `C = A(B,:)` but it didn't work (and I didn't expect it to..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s *colon simulating capability* that leverages a duo of `bsxfun(@le` and `bsxfun(@ge` -

```
N = size(A,1)
[R,~] = find((bsxfun(@le,B(:,1),1:N) & bsxfun(@ge,B(:,2),1:N)).')
out = A(R,:)
```

Sample run #1 -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18
>> B
B =
     1     2
     4     6
>> out
out =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18
```

Sample run #2 (showcasing how overlaps are handled) -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18
>> B
B =
     1     2
     4     6
     3     5
>> out
out =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
```

---

Not a vectorized solution, but more memory efficient solution could be with the [**`colon operator`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) -

```
idx = arrayfun(@colon, B(:,1), B(:,2), 'Uni', 0)
out = A([idx{:}],:)
```

Comment: You can use `idx = cell2mat(arrayfun(@colon, B(:,1), B(:,2), 'Uni', 0).')` to directly get the `idx`

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Yes, that's another way to extract from the cell array, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The silly way to go is of course to use a `for` loop:

```
C = []; % Initialise empty matrix
for ii = 1:size(B,1)
   Ctmp = A(B(ii,1):B(ii,2),:); % Extract rows
   C = [C;Ctmp]; % Add them to the existing matrix
end
```

Comment: Or intialize with `zeros(sum(diff(B,[],2)+1),size(A,2))`. Indexing would be a bit complicated though then.

Comment: This is rather memory consuming, but being a total scrub in `bsxfun` this'd be my quick-and-dirty solution. As long as your arrays are not ridiculously large, the time difference doesn't matter too much.